# A specific integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

Consider the following integral 
$$\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos\theta} \sin^n\theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta, $$
where $a$ is a real number and $n$ is an integer.

Is it possible to relate the integral given above to any special function?

My guess is that it should be some kind of Bessel function.
But I am not able to solve it.

Comment: In general it is connected with a "regularised confluent hypergeometric function". See Wolfram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As uniquesolution commented
$$J_n=\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos(\theta)} \sin^n(\theta) \,d\theta=\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \,
   _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{a^2}{4}\right)$$ where appears [the  regularized confluent hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

However, for specific values of $n$, the expressions look "nicer"
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & J_n \\
 0 & \pi  I_0(a) \\
 1 & \frac{2 \sinh (a)}{a} \\
 2 & \frac{\pi  }{a}I_1(a)\\
 3 & \frac{4 a \cosh (a)-4 \sinh (a)}{a^3} \\
 4 & \frac{3 \pi  }{a^2}I_2(a) \\
 5 & \frac{16 \left(\left(a^2+3\right) \sinh (a)-3 a \cosh (a)\right)}{a^5} \\
 6 & \frac{15 \pi }{a^3} I_3(a) \\
 7 & \frac{96 \left(a \left(a^2+15\right) \cosh (a)-3 \left(2 a^2+5\right) \sinh
   (a)\right)}{a^7} \\
 8 & \frac{105 \pi  }{a^4}I_4(a) \\
 9 & \frac{768 \left(\left(a^4+45 a^2+105\right) \sinh (a)-5 a \left(2
   a^2+21\right) \cosh (a)\right)}{a^9} \\
 10 & \frac{945 \pi  }{a^5}I_5(a)
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, if $n$ is even,

$$J
_{2n}=\sqrt{\pi }\, \left(\frac 2a\right)^n  \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) I_n(a)=\pi \frac{(2n-1)!!}{a^n}I_n(a)$$ where you see the Bessel functions you suspected.

For odd values of $n$, I did not find anything simple.

Comment: It's essentially the same, except that $2^{n/2} a^{-n/2} \neq (2/a)^{n/2}$ for odd $n$. For $a \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$,
$$\int_0^\pi e^{a \cos \theta} \sin^n \theta \,d\theta =
2^{n/2} a^{-n/2} \sqrt \pi \,\Gamma \!\left( \frac {n + 1} 2 \right) I_{n/2}(a).$$

Comment: @Maxim. Very good point ... which I missed ! Thanks.